# error trying to filter a field

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to filter a select field based on the previous selection but it is not working and it gives me an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   optgroup[label=Door-to-Door Sales ]

```
<select id="affiliation" name="affiliate[industry]">
    <option value="">Industry</option>
    <option value="3">Auto Sales</option>
    <option value="1">Door-to-Door Sales</option>
    <option value="10">Independent</option>
    <option value="11">Mortgage Officer</option>
    <option value="12">Real Estate Agent</option>
    <option value="13">Seminar Services</option>
  </select>

  <select id="companies" name="affiliate[parent_affiliate_id]">
    <option value="">Company</option>
    <optgroup label="Auto Sales"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Door-to-Door Sales ">
    <option value="3">Vivint Smart Home</option>
    <option value="4">Vivint Solar</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Independent"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Mortgage Officer"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Real Estate Agent"></optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Seminar Services">
    <option value="5">RoryRicord.com</option>
    </optgroup>
  </select>
```

The jQuery I got is based on this tutorial https://www.rubyplus.com/articles/3691-Dynamic-Select-Menus-in-Rails-5

```
jQuery(function() {
    var companies;
    companies = $('#companies').html();
    console.log(companies);
    return $('#affiliation').change(function() {
        var industry, options;
        industry = $('#affiliation :selected').text();
        options = $(companies).filter("optgroup[label=" + industry + "]").html();
        console.log(options);
        if (options) {
            return $('#companies').html(options);
        } else {
            return $('#companies').empty();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it was missing the double quotes.  so I change the double quotes to single quotes and added the double quotes in the after [ and before ]

```
options = $(companies).filter('optgroup[label="' + industry + '"]').html();
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your browser is having trouble rendering the current jquery. 
try

```
options = $(companies).filter("optgroup<label=" + industry + ">").html()
```

Comment: It didn't work. I inspect and it says `at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (VM3376 select-button.js:8)` would it be that I messed with one of the names and it doesn't know what to change?